# Update state on react not getting right value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic navigation removable tabs using [Fluent for react](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/menu/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#usage-tab-list)
[image]

I would like that when I close a tab ( for example `test3`) , the focus gets on the last tab in the nav bar like bellow

[image]

my actual problem is that when I close a tab , I loose the focus.

[image]

Here's my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Menu, tabListBehavior } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { CloseIcon } from "@fluentui/react-icons-northstar";
class MenuExampleTabShorthand extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0
    };
  }
  items = [
    {
      key: "editorials",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={() => this.closeClick("editorials")}
          />
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      key: "review",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test2"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={() => this.closeClick("review")}
          />
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      key: "events",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test3"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={() => this.closeClick("events")}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];
  closeClick = task => {
    this.setState(function(prev, props) { // Im setting the selectedIndex to 0 
      return { ...prev, selectedIndex:0 };
    });
    this.items = this.items.filter(elm => elm.key !== task);

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        activeIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
        onActiveIndexChange={(i, j) => {
          this.setState(function(prev, props) {
            return { ...prev, selectedIndex: j.activeIndex };
          });
        }}
        items={this.items}
        underlined
        primary
        accessibility={tabListBehavior}
        aria-label="Today's events"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MenuExampleTabShorthand;
```

Here's a reproduction of error [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-c4ru0?file=/example.js:0-1905)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is caused by event propagation, you can fix it by adding [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in close click event handler, and not having it will cause the active item click handler to fire and then set the current active item to the one removed ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-vhl14?file=/example.js)), note that I'm passing the event object to `closeClick`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Menu, tabListBehavior } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { CloseIcon } from "@fluentui/react-icons-northstar";

class MenuExampleTabShorthand extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0
    };
  }
  items = [
    {
      key: "editorials",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={e => this.closeClick("editorials", e)}
          />
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      key: "review",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test2"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={e => this.closeClick("review", e)}
          />
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      key: "events",
      content: (
        <div>
          "test3"
          <Button
            icon={<CloseIcon />}
            text
            iconOnly
            title="Close"
            onClick={e => this.closeClick("events", e)}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];
  closeClick = (task, e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState(function(prev, props) {
      return { ...prev, selectedIndex: 0 };
    });
    console.log(this.items);
    this.items = this.items.filter(elm => elm.key !== task);
    console.log(this.items);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        activeIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
        onActiveIndexChange={(i, j) => {
          this.setState(function(prev, props) {
            return { ...prev, selectedIndex: j.activeIndex };
          });
        }}
        items={this.items}
        underlined
        primary
        accessibility={tabListBehavior}
        aria-label="Today's events"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MenuExampleTabShorthand;
```

Comment: Wow, nice find. Why does the button's click event propagation cause the state not to be set correctly on click?

Comment: the issue is the close event triggered and then since the close button is inside the menu item the mouse click will trigger item selection event too , so you have stop event propagation using [e.stopPropagation();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Glad to help! please consider accepting my answer if its useful to you.

Comment: I would if I could. I did not ask the question :P

Comment: LOL, didn't notice, sorry :P I though you are  the question author.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was going to gave up and try another UX solution ( The author )

Comment: @infodev Glad to help , yesterday I was in a rush that's why I didn't notice who post the comments 